# unity3dにてオリジナルメッシュの頂点colorを変化させた際の適用される順番を変更したい

Tags: c#, unity3d

頂点カラーの、
〜100はColor.blue。
100〜200はColor.cyan。
200〜300はColor.gray
のようにオリジナルメッシュの頂点のカラーを変更したのですが、下図

[image: ![オリジナルメッシュ]

のように縦縞状態に分割されてしまいます。

1. これを横縞状態になるように分割したい、
2. つまり二次元配列と同じ順序に頂点カラーを変更出来ないでしょうか？

最終的にMeshのmesh.colorsに代入する際の順序を変更する、もしくはmesh.colorsの順序そのものを変更する事だと思うのですが、方法が全くわかりません……。

直接的な方法でなくても、こうすれば意図している事（2.）ができる！
と言うやり方をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、
どうか回答よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

「オリジナルメッシュ」は、横縞になるような形状（分割がされてる）でしょうか？
前提条件として、頂点が横縞状に分割されていなければ colorsだけを変更しても横縞にはなりません。

また、最終的に上図のような平面メッシュでよければ、メッシュ自体を自作するほうがコントロールしやすいかと思います。頂点とカラーを全部配列で用意して mesh.vertices に頂点配列を入れます。

もし「オリジナルメッシュ」が横縞にも対応できる形状でかつ「オリジナルメッシュ」を使わないといけない状況でしたら、colorsに設定する色の順序そのものを変更します。「0~100が青」としているところを例えば「((i / 4) % 6 == 0)なら青」のように剰余を使って色を設定します。（※ ← の計算はメッシュ形状に合わせて変更してください）

Comment: オリジナルメッシュは二次元配列と同じ順序で並んでいます。
ちょうど今はcolorsに設定する順序そのものを変更するための計算式を考えていました。

返答ありがとうございます。どうやら自力でなんとかなりそうです。